# Getting template error while templating string: No filter named 'relpath'

Tags: ansible

Getting below msg when running playbook (OS - macOS 12.3.1 (21E258))

```
TASK [metrics-base : Copy riemann files] *********************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

template error while templating string: No filter named 'relpath'.. String: {{ metrics_base_location }}/{{ item.path | relpath(role_path ~ '/files/') }}
```

Task:

```
- name: Copy riemann files
  become: true
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: "{{ metrics_base_location }}/{{ item.path | relpath(role_path ~ '/files/') }}"
    mode: preserve
  loop: "{{ riemann_files.files }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ metrics_base_location }}/{{ item.path | relpath(role_path ~ '/files/') }}"
```

I installed ansible via pip virtual env

Ansible version:

```
ansible 2.9.14
  config file = /Users/priyaranjan.m/Work/grey_orange/butler/gtp-deployer/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/priyaranjan.m/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/priyaranjan.m/Work/grey_orange/butler/gtp-deployer/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /Users/priyaranjan.m/Work/grey_orange/butler/gtp-deployer/venv/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.13 (main, May 24 2022, 21:13:51) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)]
```

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.14
  config file = /Users/priyaranjan.m/Work/grey_orange/butler/gtp-deployer/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/priyaranjan.m/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/priyaranjan.m/Work/grey_orange/butler/gtp-deployer/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /Users/priyaranjan.m/Work/grey_orange/butler/gtp-deployer/venv/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.9.13 (main, May 24 2022, 21:13:51) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)]
```

Comment: It probably does not like this bit: `role_path ~ '/files/'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a Jinja version compatibilty problem.

This reminds me of this [github issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/77356)

Try to upgrade to Ansible 2.9.22 at least

Comment: Thanks a ton! It worked, although it wasn't a smooth sail as i got some python library import error afterwards which I solved by setting ansible_python_interpreter in inventory/hosts.